# how to create a conditional column in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I create a python statement for a conditional

I have a dataframe like

```
Day   Weather   Indicator
1     Sunny     No 
2     Sunny     No
3     Dark      No
7     Dark      No
```

How can I create an conditional that lets me know if day=7 then create a new column

```
Day   Weather   Indicator
1     Sunny     No 
2     Sunny     No
3     Dark      No
7     Dark      Yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Indicator'] = np.where(df['Day'] == 7, 'Yes','No')
```

EDIT:

If exist `Indicator` column filled `No`values - [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) working nice for select rows by condition:

```
df['Indicator'] = df['Indicator'].mask(df['Day'] == 7, 'Yes')
```

---

```
df.loc[df['Day'] == 7, 'Indicator'] = 'Yes'
```

```
print (df)
   Day Weather Indicator
0    1   Sunny        No
1    2   Sunny        No
2    3    Dark        No
3    7    Dark       Yes
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael,  I edited the input column do you think you can help with the modified input statement please?

Comment: Solution is not necessary modify, working nice too. But if exist column filled `No`, then `df['Indicator'] = df['Indicator'].mask(df['Day'] == 7, 'Yes')` also working.

Answer (score 1):

`assign` +`eq`

```
df.assign(Indicator=df.Day.eq(7).map({1:'Yes',0:'No'}))
```

Comment: Or `df['Indicator'] = df['Day'].eq(7).map({True:'Yes', False:'No'})`, feel free add it to your answer

Comment: @jezrael I will keep here :-)